# Provable Hamiltonian Subclass of Barnette Graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given a bicubic planar graph consisting of faces with degree $4$ and $6$, so called Barnette graphs.
We can show that there are exactly [six squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651869/19341).
[Kundor](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1667009/19341) and [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1652520/19341) found six types of arrangements of the six squares:

1. three pairs of squares $(2+2+2)$
2. two triples arranged in row  $(\bar3+\bar3)$
3. two triples arranged like a triangle  $(3^\triangle+3^\triangle)$
4. six isolated squares $(1+1+1+1+1+1)$
5. two pairs and two isolated squares $(2+2+1+1)$
6. one pair and four isolated squares $(2+1+1+1+1)$

> Is there anything known if any of these arrangements can be proven to be Hamiltonian?

For example, "3. two triples arranged like a triangle" gives much less structural degrees of freedom compared to "4. six isolated squares"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! They are all Hamiltonian.
Paul Goodey proved in his 1975 paper [Hamiltonian circuits in polytopes with even sided faces](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02757273) ([MR410565](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=410565)) that any 3-regular planar 3-connected graph with only 4-sided or 6-sided faces is Hamiltonian.

These are exactly the graphs you are talking about, except that they are required to be 3-connected. However, any bicubic planar graph which is only 2-connected has some faces with at least 8 sides; any bicubic planar graph with only quadrilateral and hexagonal faces is 3-connected.

This is because being 2-connected but not 3-connected means there must be two faces which share more than one (non-adjacent) side, and you can quickly check that this cannot be compatible with the other requirements. (With two squares, you get digons, and I am assuming we are dealing with simple graphs. With a square and a hexagon, you get forced cut-edges, which are impossible in a regular bipartite graph. With two hexagons, you are forced to make faces with more than six sides in order to close the graph.)